# WP Query with the first post from a set of specific categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I've spent the good amount of two days looking for a way to achieve what I want, and the code below is the best I could come up with. Basically I want to get the first post from two or three select categories, merge them into a single loop and run it. The code below does just that however from what I understand it could be quite expensive to run to return just a couple of posts, so is there a better way of doing it or even a method I just have not come across?

```html
<?php
$first = new WP_Query(array('fields' => 'ids','posts_per_page' => 1,'category_name' => 'one'));
$second = new WP_Query(array('fields' => 'ids','posts_per_page' => 1,'category_name' => 'two'));

$group = array_merge($first->posts,$second->posts);
$featured = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => $group));

while ( $featured->have_posts() ) : $featured->the_post();

endwhile  ?>
```

Comment: Why not just loop your two first WP_Query objects instead? From what you have said so far (and from your code) it doesn't seem like you sort your `$group` array or anything like that. You wouldn't need that third WP_Query call that way.

Comment: The idea behind that was to have the most recent post in the group show up first, but that might be something I could just forgo for the sake of making it more efficient. Do you see any other way to do it. There is meant to be a maximum of three categories. Also how would I go about dropping the group, it's not something I have experience in.

Comment: Managed to figure out how to run the two query by themselves, but any other ideas how to go about it? It gets the job done but an entire query for each post just seems overkill

Answer (score 0):

Find posts in any of the categories:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'one,two'
);
$featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) {
    // Start looping over the query results.
    while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) {
        $featured_query->the_post();
        // Contents of the queried post results go here.
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Find posts in all of the categories:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'one+two'
);
$featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) {
    // Start looping over the query results.
    while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) {
        $featured_query->the_post();
        // Contents of the queried post results go here.
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I did try this, but the '+' does not seem to work for me at all, only the regular ',' separator. The best solution I've managed to come up with so far is the one I've added here, although I still feel it could be done in a better way

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I've put together since asking the question. Works just fine but still open to any other ideas if it still seems an expensive query

```html
$group = array('one','two','three');
foreach ( $group as $category ) {
$featured = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 1,'category_name' => $category));
while ($featured->have_posts()) { $featured->the_post(); }}
```